# Remove auto-generated prefixes from `pivot_longer` output

Tags: r, r-markdown, tidyverse, kableextra, broom

How do I remove the `(Intercept)_` and `(carat)_` prefixes in my table? That way, I could shrink my table's width a little bit and remove name redundancy.

Using `names_prefix = ""` in `pivot_longer()` or `pivot_wider()` or both, similar to  [pivot_longer issue from tidyr documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66374717/pivot-longer-issue-from-tidyr-documentation) doesn't help.

[image]

The code to make the table is

```
library(emmeans)
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
library(kableExtra)


models_ci <- diamonds %>% group_by(cut, color) %>% 
           do(data.frame(tidy(lm(price ~ carat, data = .), conf.int=T )))

models_ci[,1:5] %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols=c(estimate, std.error), names_prefix = "") %>% 
 pivot_wider(names_from = c(term, name), 
             values_from = value) %>%
  kbl(booktabs = T,
          linesep = "",
          digits = 2,
    caption = "95% confidence intervals") %>%
  add_header_above(c("Effects" = 2 , "Intercept" = 2, "Slope" = 2)) %>% 
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("repeat_header"))
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `setNames` wtih `gsub`

`setNames(gsub('\\(Intercept)_', "", colnames(.)))`

`setNames(gsub('\\carat_', "", colnames(.)))`

```
library(emmeans)
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
library(kableExtra)

models_ci <- diamonds %>% group_by(cut, color) %>% 
  do(data.frame(tidy(lm(price ~ carat, data = .), conf.int=T )))

models_ci[,1:5] %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols=c(estimate, std.error), names_prefix = "") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(term, name), 
              values_from = value) %>%
  setNames(gsub('\\(Intercept)_', "", colnames(.))) %>% 
  setNames(gsub('\\carat_', "", colnames(.))) %>% 
  kbl(booktabs = T,
      linesep = "",
      digits = 2,
      caption = "95% confidence intervals") %>%
  add_header_above(c("Effects" = 2 , "Intercept" = 2, "Slope" = 2)) %>% 
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("repeat_header"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One solution with `colnames<-`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
library(kableExtra)


models_ci <- diamonds %>% group_by(cut, color) %>% 
  do(data.frame(tidy(lm(price ~ carat, data = .), conf.int=T )))

models_ci[,1:5] %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols=c(estimate, std.error)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(term, name), 
              values_from = value) %>%
  `colnames<-`(c("cut", "color", "estimate", "std.error", "estimate", "std.error")) %>%
  kbl(booktabs = T,
      linesep = "",
      digits = 2,
      caption = "95% confidence intervals") %>%
  add_header_above(c("Effects" = 2 , "Intercept" = 2, "Slope" = 2)) %>% 
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("repeat_header"))
```

-output

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful when ones have to detail names some more, such as cap, lower case, italics,...